# Min max optimization of convex indefinite function (2)

Tags: optimization, game-theory, maxima-minima

Note this question is similar to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815763/min-max-optimization-of-convex-indefinite-function/2816694#2816694), but it here I have added some constraints to avoid a trivial outcome.

Define the following function:

$$\Delta(p,y) = \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i y^T M_i^T M_i y - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^n y^T M_j^T M_j y$$
$$\Delta(p,y) = y^T \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n p_i M_i^T M_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^n  M_j^T M_j\right) y$$

where $p$ lives on the $n$-simplex ($p_i > 0, \sum_i p_i = 1$). The matrix $M_i^T M_i$ is symmetric, thus has non-negative eigenvalues, and is of size $d \times d$. $y$ is a real-valued vector of size $d$, furthermore, we may assume that $|| y ||_2 \leq \Lambda$. Furthermore, to avoid trivially that everything becomes zero, consider the two constraints:

1. $y \neq 0$.
2. $||y|| = \Lambda$.

Is it then possible to compute, approximate or bound

$$\max_{y} \min_{p} \Delta(p,y)$$

I was thinking to apply a minimax theorem (such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem)), however, the maximization with respect to $y$ is generally not concave, since if we subtract the matrices the resulting matrix might become indefinite, and therefore it seems I cannot apply the theorem (the minimization in $p$ is convex though).

In order to use a minimax theorem I think it might be useful to consider mixed strategy for the max-player as well, so perhaps it is more tractable to compute:

$$\max_{p_y} \min_{p} \int p_y(y) \Delta(p,y) dy$$

In this case I think it will be possible to use a minimax theorem such as [Parthasarathy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthasarathy%27s_theorem)

I'm particularly interested under which conditions $\max_{y} \min_{p} \Delta(p,y) < 0$ and $\max_{p_y} \min_{p} \int p_y(y) \Delta(p,y) dy < 0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Side note: the constraints $y\neq0$ and $\|y\|=\Lambda$ are redundant if $\Lambda>0$ (the latter implies the former)

Answer (score 1):

The inner problem is the minimization of an affine function over the simplex. By the [maximum principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846633/what-is-the-name-of-this-theorem-convex-set/2847161#2847161), there is always a corner point of the simplex where the minimum value is attained. So, your problem simplifies to
$$\forall y : ||y||=\Lambda, \; \exists i : y^T \left(M_i^T M_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^n  M_j^T M_j\right) y <0?$$
To answer this question, you can precompute the eigenspaces of $M_i^T M_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^n  M_j^T M_j$ corresponding to negative eigenvalues, and see if they span $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Hi LinAlg, could you be a bit more precise? For each $i$, we need the eigenspace of $\bar{M}_i = M_i^TM_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_j M_j^T M_j$ corresponding to the negative eigenvalue. Lets call such an eigenspace $E_i$. I think if one $E_i$ spans $R^d$, we are done. Otherwise, I think the union of all $E_i$ should be $R^d$. However, I think it may be possible that we do not span $R^d$ while still for all y $y^T \bar{M} y < 0$ for all $||y|| = \Lambda$. For example, if a negative eigenvalue is much larger in magnitude than the positive eigenvalues, these matrices $\bar{M}$ might still be useful.

Comment: @Tom I agree with your comment until "I think". The assertion from the maximum principle states that for each $y$, there must be an $i$ for which $y^T \bar{M}_i y < 0$, which means that $y \in E_i$.

Comment: to clarify one more thing, if one of the $E_i$'s would span $R^d$ this is sufficient such that the max min value becomes negative. However, do you agree that this condition is not necessary? For example, if enough matrices $\bar{M}_i$ have large negative eigenvalues and small positive eigenvalues, the max min could still be negative. Do you agree?

Comment: "enough matrices $\bar{M}_i$" is too vague, what you need is that the union of the negative eigenspaces is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for each $y$ there is an $i$ such that $y \in E_i$.