# What is the name of this theorem? convex set

Tags: algebraic-topology, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, invariance

I have seen this theory but I am wondering what is the name of this theorem?

If

$~~~~~~$ 1- $\mathbb D$ is a closed convex set and real

$~~~~~~$ 2- $f:\mathbb D \rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a convex function,

$~~~~~~$ 3- $f$ has a maximum over $\mathbb D$

Then

$~~~~~~$ The maximum of $f$ is at an extreme point of $\mathbb D$.

Comment: Your theorem is false.  Take the all-zero function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  There are no extreme points of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Michael - presumably he means a strict maximum. Indeed this is true even if the strict maximum is only local.

Comment: @Adams, $\Bbb C$ is not an arbitrary closed convex set. $\Bbb C$ is the set of all complex numbers. Please do not use standard symbols to mean things other than their standard meanings. You want "$C$", not "$\Bbb C$". Can you imagine trying to read someone's matriculation of a circle where they used $\pi$ as the radius, and $r$ as the symbol for $3.14...$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, good point. In some applications we do not even notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the [*Maximum Principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) for convex functions. (See the final sentence of the introduction.)

If a maximum occurred at an interior point, then any line segment passing through the point would have ends at lower value than the middle point where the maximum occurs, violating convexity.

Comment: Many thanks. Should't the convexity be limited to strong convex cases?

Comment: @Adams - why? The short argument I gave does not rely on strongness of the convexity. It does require the maximum to be strict (though this condition can be loosened). It also requires the set to be locally convex, to ensure that there are line segments extending though an interior maximum. It also requires the set to be convex to ensure such segments cannot be extended to full lines.

Comment: My concern is about Michael's comment for $f=0$ which has maximum in the interior.

Comment: I see in my last comment I said "requires the set to be convex" when I meant to say "requires the set to be compact". Weak convexity is not the issue with Michael's example. The issue is lack of a border. Simple convexity is enough to say that from any interior point, there is some direction in which the function does not decrease. By moving in that direction, you can be assured the function will never have a lower value than it does currently. If a compact set, eventually you will reach a border, so your maximum also occurs there. But if your set is unbounded, you may not reach one.